# Filtering nested foreign keys in Django

Tags: django

I'm creating a Scrum board app.

An organization can have multiple Boards, and a Board can have many Tasks.

I'm trying to create a view which contains all tasks of the organization one is in.

To simplify:

*models.py of various apps*

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

*views.py*

```
def home(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.filter(**NOT SURE HOW TO FILTER**)

    context = {
        'tasks': tasks,
    }
    return render(request, 'tasks/home.html', context)
```

Currently, in the `**NOT SURE HOW TO FILTER**` I'm trying `board.organization=request.user.profile.organization`.

However, I get the error `SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?`

It looks like this is because of `board.organization`. On the one hand, I need to reference the organization through the Task's board. On the other hand, Django doesn't accept this.

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
tasks = Task.objects.filter(board__organization=request.user.profile.organization)
```

**NOTE:** You should use [**`@login_required(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator to ensure the user authentication

#### References

1. [Django ORM making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/)
2. [Django orm: Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)